# how to split and push into an array from server json response

Tags: javascript

```
var jvar = '{"name":"sumit","age":"33"}';
var stdata = JSON.parse(jvar);

console.log( stdata.name ); //gives sumit
 but when i'm  give the variable value like jvar 
var jvar = '{"name":"sumit"},{"age":"33"}';// my json response look like this
var stdata = JSON.parse(jvar);

console.log( stdata.name );
```

its not working

please help

Answer (score 0):

According to [JSON syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) curly braces hold objects and square brackets hold arrays. In your code, ypu have two different JSON object and they are not embraced by square brackets. It seems your server json response is inaccurate. Your code should look like:

```
var jvar = '[{"name":"sumit"},{"age":"33"}]';
var stdata = JSON.parse(jvar);

var resultArray = [];
resultArray.push(jvar);

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: .its not working.sir this is my code. $scope.mems=data.mems; // this is the json response get from the server var data1 = JSON.parse($scope.mems); var resultarray = []; resultarray.push(data1); console.log(resultarray);

Comment: Please help sir.

Comment: above code show the output  look like [{"name":"sumit"},{"age":"33"}]
but sir i want only name not total array i want to show only sumit and 33 not whole array .please help sir.

Comment: Try this: `var jvar = '[{"name":"sumit"},{"name":"aa"},{"name":"gg"}]';
var stdata = JSON.parse(jvar);

var resultArray = [];
for (var ln = 0; ln < stdata.length; ln++) {
    resultArray.push(stdata[ln]);
}
console.log(resultArray);`

Comment: show this message look like [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
here i'm  want to show like  "sumit","aa","gg"

Comment: please help sir.